# How to disable a block on form intiation and to enable the same on button click in oracle forms

Tags: properties, triggers, oracle10g, oracleforms

I am new to oracle forms. I want to disable a data block on form initiation and to enable  the same on button click.

I wrote 2 triggers 
1. "when_new_form_instance"

SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('ADD_STUDENT',enable,PROPERTY_FALSE);

2."when_button_pressed"

SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('ADD_STUDENT',enable,PROPERTY_TRUE);

Its throwing some error that "no such property for SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY"

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: The property you're thinking of is `ENABLED`, but it is only applicable to items. You could loop through all the items in a block and set their `ENABLED` property to `PROPERTY_FALSE`, but I'd prefer one or more of nightfox79's suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

You can't disable a block. You have 2 options:

1. If it is on a tabpage put the enable, of visible property of the tabpage to false.
2. Put the following propertys to false: insert_allowed, update_allowed, delete_allowed, query_allowed. After that you can't do anything in the block.

Answer (score 0):

You can not enable disable complete block in one command.
you will have to set disable all items one by one.